# Set reminder in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, timer, reminders

I want to ask how I can set a reminder from a string and give you a notification 10 minutes before the exact time and after that the UI change from time a to time b.

```
let a = "04:12"
let b = "11:38"
let c = "15:00"
let d = "18:03"
let e ="18:59"
```

I am setting up the timer like this but I don't know where I should go from here. This is my code:

```
extension Date {
     var hour: Int { return Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self)}
     var minute: Int { return Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self)}
}

@objc func scheduleTime() {
    timer = Timer(fireAt: Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: DateComponents(hour: 0...23 ~= Date().hour ? 23 : 0), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
}
```

Comment: You don't need a timer. Just schedule a local notification for the required time

Comment: @Paulw11 my string time I got from api, and need to update daily. still I can do this with local notification?

Comment: Getting new times is independent of scheduling the notifications.  A timer wouldn't help you with that anyway since a timer won't run when the app isn't in the foreground.  You should also look at background refresh.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you show me how to do that? like the background refresh and thing